# MySQL 8.0 Disable or Single User Mode

Tags: mysql

OS: RHEL
DB: MySQL 8.0.x.x

Question: I have several MySQL DBs on 2 servers, I am not sure if they are being used by our programers or staff. I have asked but no one answers. I don't want to drop/delete those DBs until I am 100% sure.

**Is there a way to disable/restrict or do something that will temporarily not allow users to use or access those DBs ?**

I should be the only one to access them and enable them later if I get complains. We need to consolidate servers and those DBs are taking up space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL version is >= 8.0.22 you could put the db into [read only mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-database.html#alter-database-read-only):

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb READ ONLY = 1;
```

You could rename the database although there is no SQL statement to do that. You would have to either, dump it and pipe it back into a db with a different name:

```
mysqldump -u username -B mydb -p | mysql -u username -p mynewdb
```

or rename all tables in SQL by running the queries output by:

```
SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE mydb.', table_name, ' TO mynewdb.', table_name, '; ')
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = 'mydb';
```

This would not move other objects like stored procs, views, etc but would be enough to find out whether people are trying to use the database.

If your users have explicit privileges granted then you could [revoke privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html) from the specific db, but this is not an option if you use global privileges for all your users.

If you use explicit privs you can use the following queries to check:

```
-- show global privileges
SELECT * FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES;

-- show schema level privileges for 'mydb'
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb';

-- show table level privileges for 'mydb'
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_PRIVILEGES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb';
```

Comment: @Shadow

Our MySQL version is on 8.0.30, so READ ONLY option will work best for me.

I am assuming that after DB has been changed to READ ONLY status, users will not be able to use it. That way, they can contact me and If needed,  I can change it back to READ ONLY = 0 ; ( 0 = back to  normal status) 

Thanks for taking the time and helping me. I really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: nnichols: Thanks so much for your help and providing details and commands to fix my issue. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please remember to accept answers if they resolve your issue.